# Redimensionar imagen con un alto fijo

Tags: php, imagen

Estoy mirando por internet y encontrado varios ejemplos de como redimensionar una imagen, pero no se como redimensionar una imagen dándole un alto fijo y que el ancho se adapte proporcionalmente a ese alto.

Pensé que seria algo fácil obteniendo el tamaño con getimagesize y con imagescale determinar el alto, penque que te calculaba el ancho automáticamente.

A ver si me podéis echar una mano, gracias

Comment: No te entedí si ya tu defines el alto, ¿Y en base a que se define el ancho?

Comment: Hola Isaac ¿podrías proveer un ejemplo con código de lo que estás intentando realizar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucione, pongo el código resultante:

```
function redimensionar($pathorigen,$pathdestino) {
    list($ancho_or, $alto_or) = getimagesize($pathorigen);  

    $ancho1 = 100 * $ancho_or;
    $ancho = $ancho1 / $alto_or;

    $alto = 100;

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho, $alto);       
    $fondo = imagecolorallocate($thumb, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefilledrectangle($thumb, 0, 0, $alto_or, $ancho_or, $fondo);

    $extension =  substr($pathorigen,-3);

    if ($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "peg") {       
        $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathorigen);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho, $alto, $ancho_or, $alto_or);
        imagejpeg($thumb,$pathdestino,72);  
    }
    else if ($extension == "png") { 
        $origen = imagecreatefrompng($pathorigen);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho, $alto, $ancho_or, $alto_or);
        imagepng($thumb,$pathdestino,6);    
    }
    else if ($extension == "gif") {     
        $origen = imagecreatefromgif($pathorigen);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho, $alto, $ancho_or, $alto_or);
        imagegif($thumb,$pathdestino);              
    }
    imagedestroy($thumb);
}
```

Comment: hola Isaac. me alegra que encontraras solucion. pero por favor, sigue la guia [answer]. Has de responderte como si no fueras tu el autor de la pregunta. explicando cuanto mejor puedas la respuesta, asi le valdrá a futuros usuarios con la misma duda. Un saludo